# Why my web browser crashes on Android phone when I have a lot of <span> elements under a single parent

Tags: android, html, css

I've built a page with a paragraph split into multiple spans (in the thousands).

In some Android phones (Android 12, Chrome browser), when I open the web page, the browser crashes immediately. I can't find any reference to this problem in the entire web.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved this issue by converting the `inline` elements (`<span>`) into `div`s with `display: inline-block` (and replacing the spaces with `&nbsp;`).

For some reason, the browser in Android can't handle so many inline elements under a single parent

Comment: There are dozens of browsers available for Android, both pre-installed and user-installed. There is no single "the browser in Android".

Comment: @CommonsWare updated the main question with more details. Thanks!